# Mysql Errors when exporting project from Windows to Debian

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, debian

I have a webapp running with Spring and Hibernate on Tomcat and Mysql.
I use to code on my computer : a Windows 7 based environement : the webapp works fine.

Then I tried to export it on a remote debian server so I install tomcat and mysql then import a Dump from my Windows mysql DB.

Even if I can access to my database with the mysql console, my webapp cannot and give me this error :

```
20:35:03,020 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:226 - Obtaining JDBC connection
20:35:03,021 DEBUG PoolableConnectionFactory:292 - Failed to validate a poolable connection
java.sql.SQLException: isValid() returned false
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:228)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:303)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:288)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:488)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:119)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1413)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
```

Then I search and found something about **"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"** so I add to my conf : 
    prop.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");

and now :

```
20:53:24,701 ERROR ContextLoader:331 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateMenuDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.meltdown.menu.infra.HibernateMenuDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class com.meltdown.config.ViewConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.meltdown.config.ViewConfig.sessionFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: BARS
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
```

So it looks that my application cannot access my Database but I dont understand why...

Here are my conf files : 
AppSecurityConfig 
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/bo/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    .antMatchers("/bo/bars**").access("hasRole('ROLE_SUPERADMIN')")
    .and().formLogin();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
    .ignoring()
    .antMatchers("/resources/**");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}
}
```

MVCInitializer 
    public class MVCInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
return new Class[] { ViewConfig.class };
}

 @Override
 protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
 return null;
 }

 @Override
 protected String[] getServletMappings() {
 return new String[] { "/" };
 }
}
```

ViewConfig

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.meltdown.*" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ AppSecurityConfig.class })
public class ViewConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
        builder.scanPackages("com.meltdown").addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return builder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        prop.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        prop.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        prop.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        return prop;
    }

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/meltdown2");
    ds.setUsername("root");
    ds.setPassword("myXP4NYYKF8");
    return ds;
}

//Create a transaction manager
@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager txManager() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/bo_theme/**");
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver
    = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

 @Bean
  public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000000);
    return resolver;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's the only problem, but I noticed this error in your log :

`Missing table: BARS`.

I know that mysql table names in Windows are case insensitive by default while in Linux/Unix systems they are case sensitive (I learned it the hard way, when code I developed in Windows, and worked fine on my PC, didn't work when deployed on our Linux servers).

I'm assuming your code refers to the table BARS (all upper case letters) while the table define in the DB is Bars or bars, which works on Windows, but not on Linux/Unix.

Comment: You are right! Thanks a lot!
I use lowercase in my @Table annotations in my Entities.
Then I remove the prop.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate"); because he was messing with type of columns (int instead of bigint etc...) and it works!